# Tables question for emailer

Tags: html, css

Another tables question. Before anyone suggests not using inline styles I'm doing it so that all email clients will read it. Otherwise I would not normally do this. Also I'm using tables because its got to support old email clients.

With that in mind here is the example.
http://jsfiddle.net/rcZZb/16/

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <table cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left" style="background: #fff;" cellpadding="0"; width="639">
    <tr>
      <td style="line-height:0;" colspan="2"><img src="http://www.artaholic.com/html/jsfiddle/img/header.jpg" width="639" height="84" vspace="0" hspace="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="line-height:0;" colspan="2"><img src="http://www.artaholic.com/html/jsfiddle/img/banner.jpg" width="639" height="156" vspace="0" hspace="0"></td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
          <td width="375" style="border:1px solid red;"><span style="padding:30px">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</span>
       </td>
       <td width="264" height="158" style="border:1px solid red; background: url('http://www.artaholic.com/html/jsfiddle/img/box-bg.jpg'); font: normal 15px Arial, sans-serif; color:#0098d6;"><span style="padding:20px;">
           ntium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta</span>
      </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

**Non-Inline CSS:**

```
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0
}
```

I'm trying to control the text in the 2 red border boxes. Right now it's centering both horizontally and vertically. I want to be able to control it with `padding` to specify where it should be placed inside each box. When I set my `padding` on the `td` it screws up the `background-image` on the right box by expanding it. If I place the text inside a `span` and style it with `padding` then only the first line moves in text.

How can I control the text placement inside the box without effecting the `width` of each box?

Thanks

Comment: jsFiddle is great, but at least post some of the code inline.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to position the text?

Comment: What are you referring to the inline code is in there. Would this not be described as inline code or am I missing something.        <td width="264" height="158" style="border:1px solid red; background: url('http://www.artaholic.com/html/jsfiddle/img/box-bg.jpg'); font: normal 15px Arial, sans-serif; color:#0098d6;"><span style="padding:20px;">
          </span>

Comment: Purmou I just need to add padding around the text to give it some space from been right up against the edge. The problem is when I add padding to the td is stretches the image. When I add padding to the span it does nothing but move the first line of text.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `<span>` and `<div>`; you need that element to be `diplay:block`, not `display:inline`.

I updated your jsfiddler to use both approaches: the first one is inserted with `display: block` and the second one is changed to `<div>`.: http://jsfiddle.net/rcZZb/17/

Comment: In my post I had said I can only use tables not div's because its got to support old email clients. All I need to do is control the positioning of the text inside the table cell.

Comment: which you can simply use the `style="display:block"` with the `span` you have in place...

Comment: Display block doesn't work in older outlook email. 2007 and 2008 from what I have read.

Comment: Div is also not recognized, I know I'm going mad all the tools I can't use.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I figured using a p tag instead of the span worked out. p is not an inline tag and is supported in older email clients. Thanks to all for your answers.